Unexpected behaviour in Python event loop
I have the following piece of Async code in Python.
import asyncio

async def get_some_values_from_io():
    print("Getsome value Executing...")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return [100,200]

vals = []

async def fetcher():
    while True:
        print("Fetcher Executing...")
        io_vals = await get_some_values_from_io()

        for val in io_vals:
            vals.append(io_vals)

async def monitor():
    while True:
        print("Monitor Executing...")
        print (len(vals))

        await asyncio.sleep(3)

async def main():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(fetcher())
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(monitor())
    await asyncio.gather(t1, t2)

asyncio.run(main())

print("Rest of the method is executing....")

Both the async functions being called into are calling async.sleep() method with considerable time to sleep.
While both of them sleep, the last print stetment print("Rest of the method is executing....") must be run.
But what is is getting printed is: (it just keeps going in fact)
Fetcher Executing...
Getsome value Executing...
Monitor Executing...
0
Fetcher Executing...
Getsome value Executing...
Monitor Executing...
2
...

My understanding is that the whole Python programs is just single thread (GIL) and the event loop too would share the GIL. Is it not correct?
Also, there are mentions of run_in_executor() method which says that CPU bound tasks can be run using this method outside of event loop. So this means, there is another thread running parallelly besides event loop? This contradicts the fact of GIL.

How do you think the GIL should make the output different, and why? The lock is released during I/O, and the whole point of asyncio.sleep is to task-switch and run a different eligible operation until the delay is complete, if there are any; if there isn't anything eligible, then just sleeping is normal/expected.

(In particular, why do you think asyncio.run() should return and allow Rest of the method is executing to be printed before both the tasks have completed and be gathered?)

The GIL is a lock, not a thread. Many threads can be executing python byte code, but since any instance of the byte code executor only runs if it has an exclusive lock on the GIL, only one will run at a time.

asyncio.run creates and runs an event loop. It will not return until that event loop is exited in some manner. We would not expect print("Rest of the method is executing....") to run until the event loop exits. If you have created a thread outside of the asyncio event loop, then run_in_executor would be interesting.

On this question, I made another observation and posted it in my answer below.

[This is my reply to the second question below]
This is normal Python, it's not magic :) You are calling "fetcher()" (inside the "main" coroutine when you create the task) so that fetcher coroutine will start executing -- it's doesn't matter if it's ever awaited, since it cannot know anything about future events -- but since it's a coroutine, it will be paused when it hits the first await. Similar for the other coroutine.
Since those tasks (t1 and t2) are never awaited, the main coroutine will almost immediately exit. But the prints happened before any awaits -- so those have executed. If you also add print statements after the various await statements, and then also call gather you will see the difference.
Btw - It seems a little strange to me to create these tasks from inside another coroutine. I think it would be simpler to write
async def main():
    await fetcher()
    await monitor()


I'm not sure that this is a very good explanation. Add to the main function time.sleep(10) and then print('Main Exit'). This will show that neither fetcher, nor monitor gets executed before you'll exit the main. This again shows that async execution happens in one thread and not in parallel. However what we also see that  both fetcher and monitor for some reason are added to event loop and thus they are executed just after the main.  However they are not correctly awaited and so you see them executed only once while both functions are infinite loops.

Note that I deliberately not say that those functions are executed. The interpreter will start executing them, since those functions were called. If they were normal functions they would be completely executed (unless some exception happened), but since they are coroutines, execution is interrupted by the awaits.

Async doesn't create new threads. Basically all async jobs are executed in the main thread. So your async tasks are running in the main thread that is expecting at the same time to  print("Rest of the method is executing"). As you understand single thread can only work at one of three jobs: 1) do asynctask #1 2) do asynctask #2 3) execute the very last print funciton.
However when you call asyncio.run the function takes both tasks and by definition waits till both tasks finishes. Thus it's not running the very last print function. And I'd like to mention this again that when it executes task1 and task2 in does this in the same thread, but carefully switching from first to second and back. If both tasks will finish at some point the thread will go forth and execute rest of the code.
To create desired behaviour explained in your question you need to create second thread and run couroutines in that thread. I would also suggest to use 'Queue' to communicate between threads.
import asyncio
import threading
from queue import Queue
import time

q = Queue()

async def get_some_values_from_io():
    print("Getsome value Executing...")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return [100,200]


async def fetcher():
    while True:
        print("Fetcher Executing...")
        io_vals = await get_some_values_from_io()
        for val in io_vals:
            q.put(val)

async def monitor():
    while True:
        print("Monitor Executing...")
        size = q.qsize() 
        await asyncio.sleep(3)


async def parallel():
    # run both async tasks until complete
    await asyncio.gather(monitor(), fetcher())

def main(args):
    asyncio.run(parallel())
# now add threading
thd = threading.Thread(target=main, args=(None,))
thd.start()

print("Rest of the method is executing....")

while True:
    # sleep in the main thread won't block second thread
    time.sleep(1)

Output is the following:
Rest of the method is executing....
Monitor Executing...
Fetcher Executing...
Getsome value Executing...
Monitor Executing...
Fetcher Executing...
Getsome value Executing...
Monitor Executing...
Fetcher Executing...
Getsome value Executing...
Monitor Executing...
Fetcher Executing...

using executor
You may also consider using cuncurrent.futures module instead of threading

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

...

def main():
    asyncio.run(parallel())

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
a = executor.submit(main)
print("Rest of the method is executing....")
while True:
    time.sleep(1)


Thanks Johnny! It makes things really clear.

Just to summarise: When we start running a Python script, there is an OS process created(in RAM) which has all the
resources (eg: variables, file handles etc..). This can be accessed by exactly one thread. This is what is called GIL. When we create multiple threads in Python and multiple threads can not access the OS process at once due to GIL, they tend to run sequentially by acquiring lock on the OS process. When we create the event loop, it runs as part of the main thread (given that we don't create any other threads). <>...

If we create more than one threads in the Python script, they are multiplexed by the OS and when they execute, they have the exclusive access to the OS process. Exactly this is what happens in the example that you have provided. Mine and yours is a perfect example of: asyncio library multiplexing the tasks inside event loop Vs OS multiplexing the threads in the script (in one thread the event loop runs and in another the thread created by the user runs).
Am I correct here?

I made another observation which I gave in my answer below.. That's confusing me.

Code: (almost the same as I gave in my question except the await asyncio.gather(t1,t2) is commented.
import asyncio

async def get_some_values_from_io():
    print("Getsome value Executing...")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return [100,200]

vals = []

async def fetcher():
    while True:
        print("Fetcher Executing...")
        io_vals = await get_some_values_from_io()

        for val in io_vals:
            vals.append(io_vals)

async def monitor():
    while True:
        print("Monitor Executing...")
        print (len(vals))

        await asyncio.sleep(3)

async def main():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(fetcher())
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(monitor())
    #await asyncio.gather(t1, t2)

asyncio.run(main())

print("Rest of the method is executing....")

Output:
Fetcher Executing...
Getsome value Executing...
Monitor Executing...
0
Rest of the method is executing....

The question is why all the print statements are getting executed?
what I thought was: we are just creating the tasks (t1, t2) and they are NOT awaited. So only the Rest of the method is executing.... should be printed.
Instead, only these above statements are printed.
It is NOT even running indefinitely as in the case when the await is is present.
I am puzzled of why those print statemenst from the async methods were executed exactly once.

Hi, yes, I see your example a bit confusing - when you don't have clear await statement for tasks 1 and task 2. Basically this means that you are not controlling when tasks will be executed, what might not be a good practice. But while it is a bit surprising it's easy to explain: when you call asyncio.create_task both tasks gets assigned to the event loop. So maybe as soon as you start awaiting / running loop both tasks  will eventually be executed.

Add another print inside main method after t2 = asyncio.create_task(monitor()) line. This will show that main gets executed before starting working on task1 and task2.

Add to the main function time.sleep(10) and then print('Main Exit'). This will show that neither fetcher, nor monitor gets executed before you'll exit the main. This again shows that async execution happens in one thread and not in parallel. However what we also see that both fetcher and monitor for some reason are added to event loop and thus they are executed just after the main. However they are not correctly awaited and so you see them executed only once while both functions are infinite loops.
